# how to send id from one controller to another in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a basic controller that displays my Software Group name:

```
var SoftwareGroupApp = angular.module('SoftwareGroupApp', []);
SoftwareGroupApp.controller('SoftwareGroupController', function($scope, $http) {
 $http.get("select_SoftwareGroup.php")

.then(function (response) {$scope.result = response.data.records;});
});
```

In my view I'm displaying this Software Group in a list

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
            <div ng-app="SoftwareGroupApp" ng-controller="SoftwareGroupController">
                <li ng-repeat="x in result"><a class="haschild" title="" href="">{{ x.GroupName }}</a>
                    <ul>
                    <div  ng-controller="SoftwareController">
                        <li ng-repeat="x in names"><a title="" href="">{{ x.name }}</a></li>
                    </div>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
```

and i have another controller that display my Software name :

```
var SoftwareApp = angular.module('SoftwareApp', []);
SoftwareApp.controller('SoftwareController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("selectSoftware.php") 
.then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
```

when someone click on the Software Group name, i have another sub menu that list my software name .

```
 <ul>
                    <div  ng-controller="SoftwareController">
                        <li ng-repeat="x in names"><a title="" href="">{{ x.name }}</a></li>
                    </div>
                    </ul>
```

What I'm trying to do is when someone click on the Software Group name, my Software group id save in a variable and send to my SoftwareController . and i  display names of software that == id

Comment: Why did you posted the code in images? that prevented me from answering.

Comment: Please post code as code, not as images

Comment: i post code as code

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use $rootScope.broadcast for this kind of operation. To be very short you can use broadcast like this.
I one controller where you want to send data write like this:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("yourFuction", data);
```

In the receiver controller get this data like this:

```
$rootScope.$on("yourFuction", function(data){
    //do something
});
```

check this for more information: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution would be to use uirouter, rather than ng-controller,  and pass the ID as a state parameter.

Another option would be to use components rather than ng-controller, which you can pass parameters to.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways. I will mention you one way:

You can create a service to store Id which you want to send into another controller like below:

```js
angular.module('app').factory('commonService', function () {
        var myValue;
        return {
            set: function (o) {
                this.myValue = o;
            },
            get: function () {
                return this.myValue;
            }
        };
});
```

Now, inject this service into both controller like below:

```js
angular.module('app').controller('firstController', function ($scope, commonService) {
    $scope.setValue = function (value) {
        commonService.set(value);
    };
});
```

And,

```js
angular.module('app').controller('SecondController', function ($scope, commonService) {
    $scope.getValue = function () {
        $scope.value = commonService.get();
    };
});
```